# Please help me understand this formula solution.

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I have the solution to a problem.

$$f(t)=t, \pi ≤t<\pi$$

The solution to coeffisient b_n is: $$ b_n= \frac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)sin(nt) dt=\frac{2}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_{0}^\pi f(t)sin(nt) dt$$

so $$\frac{1}{\pi}$$ becomes $$\frac{2}{\pi}$$ and $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)sin(nt) dt$$ becomes $$\int_{0}^\pi f(t)sin(nt) dt$$

Can someone please explain?

Comment: the product of two odd functions, such as $f(t)=t$ and $\sin(nt)$,  is an even function, and the integral of an even function over a symmetric interval, such as $[-\pi,\pi],$ is twice the value of its integral over the interval $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two odd functions, such as $f(t)=t$ and $\sin(nt)$,  is an even function,

and the integral of an even function over a symmetric interval, such as $[-\pi,\pi],$

is twice the value of its integral over the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much. I didn't know about this special rule. Are there similar special rules for a product of two even functions over a symmetrical interval, and the product of an odd and an even function over a symmetrical interval?

Comment: The product of two even functions is also an even function, the product of an even function and an odd function is an odd function, and the integral of an odd function from $−\pi$ to $\pi$ is zero

Comment: Thanks. But, what I meant was, when you say the integral of an even function over a symmetric interval is twice the value of its integral over the interval [0,]. Is there a special rule like this, for integrals of an odd function over a symmetric interval?

Comment: as I said, the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval is $0$

Comment: Thanks. My head isn't working right now. I guess its time to sleep. I spent my whole day trying to figure this out. Its a shame my book doesn't mention this anywhere. Feel like I wasted a whole day. Thank you so much for the help. Hopefully, tomorrow will be a productive day.